# object list always print nil in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In my object Dish `xxx.Dish`, I want to access the **Choice** class    `price` and `name` to display but I failed. dish data load from web API and I tested data loaded success full and put the data to the object dish and it return the object list to **viewcontroller** to load tableview.

Output of printed console

> Optional([xxx.Dish, xxx.Dish])

and in the dish class before append `optionList?.append(_obj)`

> xxx.DishOption

Anyone helps me how can I do that .. I am new to swift and is it right way to implement? Please suggest me?

```
class Dish {
        let dishId : String
        var optionList : [DishOption]?

        init?(fromAPIResponse resposne : Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) {

            guard let dishId = resposne["dishId"] as? String else {
                return nil

            }
            self.dishId = dishId
            if let objs =  resposne["options"] as?  [[String: AnyObject]]{

                for obj in objs {
                    if  let _obj = DishOption(fromAPIResponse: obj){

                        optionList?.append(_obj)

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        class DishOption {

            let optionId : String

            var choiceList : [Choice]?

            init?(fromAPIResponse resposne : Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) {

                guard let  optionId = resposne["optionId"] as? String else {
                    return nil
                }

                self.optionId = optionId

                if let objs =  resposne["choices"] as?  [[String: AnyObject]]{

                    for obj in objs {
                        if  let _obj = Choice(fromAPIResponse: obj){

                            choiceList?.append(_obj)

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        class Choice{

            let choiceId : String
            let name : String
            let price : String

            init?(fromAPIResponse resposne : Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) {
                guard let choiceId = resposne["choiceId"] as? String ,
                    let name = resposne["name"]  as? String,
                    let price = resposne["price"] as? String else {

                        return nil
                }
                self.choiceId = choiceId
                self.name = name
                self.price = price

            }

    }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
     var  dishMenuList = [Dish]()
            guard let objs = json["menu_list"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] else {
                return
            }

            for obj in objs {

                if let _obj = Dish(fromAPIResponse: obj){

                 print(_obj.optionList) //always print nil  


                if let options = _obj.optionList {

                    for data in options {

                        print(data.displayAsButton)

                    }
                   }
                   dishMenuList.append(_obj)
                }

            }
```

Comment: You should take both the classes DishOption and Choice out of the Dish class and place them at the same level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see, you are never initializing both the optionList and choiceList arrays. It would be better to initialize them as empty arrays:

```
class Dish {
        let dishId : String
        var optionList = [DishOption]()
...

       optionList.append(_obj)
```

This is the reason that you cannot see any options. Since the optionList is still nil, the line `optionList?.append(_obj)` does not execute.

Comment: could you tell me please .. did i violation  solid pattern any rule

Comment: could you check this please http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/157401/did-i-violation-solid-pattern-any-rule